# how to change width using bootstrap during responsiveness?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the width of the div elements during responsiveness.
so when I reduce the screen width to around 600px the div elements should increase their width to 50%.

Now I noticed no breakpoint for w-* class, and was wondering is there any way to do it??

also I'm allowed to only use bootstrap and avoid as much as possible to add my own CSS.

can any one help??

here is the code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .d-flex>div
  {
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
  margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="card bg-light">
                            <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                                <div class="flex-grow-1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Manually create media queries. There are some instances where you can not fully rely on Bootstrap alone.

Comment: Thanks, but I was  to avoid  adding my own queries,
is there no other way??

Comment: There is one thing, you can use Bootstrap's grid system since you are already using Boostrap. But seems like you need to do it on your own since you wanted to set the div's width to 50% and a breakpoint of 600px and its kind of a mess to override or change code in the bootstrap's css file because it has default breakpoints in changing width of a column (1199px, 991px, 768px, 480px) and yours wanted to be 600px. Much easy if you would do it on your own.

Comment: hmm...that would really mess up my structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with pinch of jquery code like below,

```
if(jQuery(window).width() < 601px){
    jQuery('.your-div-class').addClass('w-50');
}
else {
    jQuery('.your-div-class').removeClass('w-50');
}
```

Please make sure you have included jquery in your page as well.

Comment: sorry mate, can't use jquery or javascript, i'm not allowed in this.

Comment: Trying to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: You should add a custom breakpoint from 600px , because it is the simplest and most efficient method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's break points are Small 540px and Medium 720px. So you could try the following. This example defaults to 5 blocks per row, and then 2 blocks per row on a small break point.:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .d-flex {
      height: 200px;
      background-color: black;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card bg-light">
      <div class="card-body row">
        <div class="d-flex col-6 col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex col-6 col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex col-6 col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex col-6 col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex col-6 col-sm-2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: helpful but not useful, the code is not very efficient.
but I get the logic of it.